# Processing group of items from List or Array

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a string of text with items separated by a semicolon.  There could be one, a couple, or hundreds of these items.

I need to process these items in batches of up to 100.  I can use an array or a list, either is fine.  However, LINQ is not an option.

I can come up with clunky ways of doing this, but is there a way to do this that is both efficient and tight?

Comment: How do you define **process**?

Comment: Could you provide the method that you have that is too "clunky"?

Comment: I need to send 100 emails at a time. So something like SendEmail(ListOfOneHundredEmails);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, 
                                                   int batchSize)
{
    List<T> nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        nextbatch.Add(item);
        if (nextbatch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return nextbatch;
            nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (nextbatch.Count > 0)
        yield return nextbatch;
}
```

and use this

```
var result = Batch("item1;item2;item3".Split(';'), 100);
```

Comment: `Batch` looks like an extension method. They were introduced in C# 3.0. The OP is using C# 2.0.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Corrected. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Of you don't even want to store more than 100 of these at a time in memory, you can loop over the first 100 matches using `String.Split`:

```
string input; //your string
int i;
string[] inputArray; //tring split on semicolon goes here
while(true)
{
    inputArray = input.Split(new char[]{";"}, 101) //only split on first 101 times
    if (inputArray.Count <= 100) //last iteration
    {
        for (i = 0; i < inputArray.Count; i++)
            SendEmail(inputArray[i]);
        break;
    }
    else //will have left over for another loop
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            SendEmail(inputArray[i]);
        input = inputArray[100];
    }
};
```

I'm sure there are ways to optimize this, but the basic idea - to use the `count` feature of `Split` to avoid working with them all - may be the best way to solve your problem.